# Difference between .SQL and .DUMP files

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-backups, database-restore

When I do a `mysqldump` operation I get a `.SQL` file. I have never created a `.DUMP` file but was able to restore a database from a `.DUMP` file with the same operations("<" or SOURCE) I use to restore a database from a `.SQL` file.

So what's the difference between these two file types?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Calling a mysql dump `.sql` is just a convenient convention. You could call the files `.foo` or `.arglebargle` if you wanted. MySQL doesn't care. It just expects to be fed SQL statements when the dump's reloaded, regardless of what the filename actually is.

Comment: It doesn't matter what extension we append to a file? Is this unique to MYSQL? if not, what other programming languages/systems?

Comment: filename extensions are an msdos-ism that's bee perpetuated through the industry as a quick/dirty way of identifying a file's type/content. Given modern file systems which have multiple methods of attaching metadata to a file, there's absolutely no reason we have to keep (say) calling all word files `.doc`. The fact that it's a Word file can be recorded in the metadata and you could theoretically rename that file `resume.exe` and still fire up Word.

Comment: It's basically just social inertia and worshiping at the altar of backwards compatibility that keeps this going. MySQL doesn't care the extension is, because it just wants to see SQL statements when it reads the file's contents. If that sql comes from a .sql or a .txt or a .exe file is irrelevant. sql is sql.